# Deploy heroku app with private git repo in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

I've made a rails app, and want to deploy it to Heroku. However, `git push heroku master` is failing because it doesn't have permission to access a gem referenced in the gemfile (as the repository is private). This line is producing the error.

`gem 'auth', branch: 'master', git: 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/auth.git'`

First I looked [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys), and so I tried generating a *new* set of public and private keys and then transferring them over with `heroku keys:add`, but it wouldn't accept a private key.

I also tried [this](https://coderwall.com/p/szhuig/ssh-into-your-heroku-app) to simulate an ssh and ran `heroku run bash`, then tried to run `ssh-keygen`, but the files in there were temporary and disappeared when I tried to run the server.

Comment: matts1, did my answer help solve your problem?

Comment: It's definitely not optimal, but as you said, AFAIK it's the only available option. I'll use it till I find a better solution, but until then, it'll have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by putting the `username` and `password` into the URL, as in Basic HTTP Auth, e.g.

```
gem 'my_gem', :git => 'https://my_username:my_password@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git', :ref => 'revision_no'
```

If you don't want to put the `password` into the `Gemfile`, then you can put it into an `environment variable`.

On Heroku you can add the environment variables using this command:

```
heroku config:add ENV_VAR=VALUE
```

and then in the `Gemfile` you'd use this environment variable, like this:

```
gem 'my_gem',
      :git => "https://#{ENV['var_private_gem_username']}:#{ENV['var_private_gem_password']}@github.com/my_github_account.git",
      :ref => 'rev'
```

To avoid having to use HTTPS during development, you could also try splitting up development and production modes, like so:

```
group :development do
    gem 'auth', branch: 'master', git: 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/auth.git'
end
group production do
    gem 'my_gem',
      :git => "https://#{ENV['var_private_gem_username']}:#{ENV['var_private_gem_password']}@github.com/my_github_account.git",
      :ref => 'rev'
end
```

*Note*: Neither method is 100% secure. But, the second option (storing in the heroku's environment variable) is more secure than the first option (storing them in a plain text). But, there is no other alternatives to do such thing (AFAIK).